# A monthly expenses calculator for an assignment

Tags: c#, homework

I've been working on this project for a day. Any feedback on the code would be appreciated. The code is for an assignment. The main concern I have with the project is that I'm not using abstract classes correctly.

**Expenses.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ValidateTypeLibrary;
namespace ExpensesCalculator
{
public abstract class Expenses
{
    public delegate void ExpensesWarning(IDictionary<string,decimal> expenses);
    public abstract decimal MonthlyLoanPayment(); // Abstract method 
    public void GetMonthlyExpenses(ExpensesWarning expensesWarning)
    {
        int option;
        monthlyExpenses = new Dictionary<string,decimal>();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following values:");

        Console.Write("a) Gross monthly income (before deductions): ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Income", GetExpenses()); 

        Console.Write("b) Estimated tax deducted: ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Tax", GetExpenses());
        expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        Console.WriteLine("c) Estimated monthly expenditures in each of the following categories: ");

        Console.Write("i) Groceries: ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Groceries", GetExpenses());
        expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        Console.Write("ii) Water and lights: ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Utlities", GetExpenses());
        expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        Console.Write("iii) Travel costs (including petrol):");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Tavel", GetExpenses());
        expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        Console.Write("ii) Cellphone and Telephone: ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Phone", GetExpenses());
        expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        Console.Write("ii) Other expenses: ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Other", GetExpenses());
        expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to rent ('1') or buy property ('2') ?: ");
        option = GetOption();

        if (option == 1)  // User enters the value of their rent per month

        {

            RentPayment();
            expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        }
        else // User enters details of the house they will be applying for a loan to buy a house

        {

            HomeLoanPayment();
            expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy a vehicle? ('1' Yes) or ('2' NO): ");
        option = GetOption();

        if (option == 1)
        {
            VehiclePayment();
            expensesWarning(monthlyExpenses);

        }

        DisplayExpenses();

    }
    private void DisplayExpenses()

    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your remaining month for the month after all deductions is: {GetRemainingMoney():C2}");

        Console.WriteLine("Your monthly expenses in descending order:");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Expense \t Amount");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");

        monthlyExpenses.OrderBy(key => key.Value);

        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyExpenses.Count; i++)

        {

            if (monthlyExpenses.ElementAt(i).Key != "Income")

            {

                Console.WriteLine($"{monthlyExpenses.ElementAt(i).Key} \t {monthlyExpenses.ElementAt(i).Value:C2}");

            }

        }

    }
    private void HomeLoanPayment()
    {
        HomeLoan homeLoan = new HomeLoan();
        monthlyExpenses.Add("HomeLoan", homeLoan.MonthlyLoanPayment()); // Uses the A= P(1+in) formula
        

        Console.WriteLine($"Your monthly repayment for the house is {monthlyExpenses["HomeLoan"]:C2}");

        if (monthlyExpenses["HomeLoan"] > (monthlyExpenses["Income"] * 0.33M)) // The user loan should be more than a third of their gross income for a likely approval of a home loan
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\aApproval of home loan is unlikely");

        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Approval of home loan is likely");

        }
    }
    private void VehiclePayment()
        
    {

        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        monthlyExpenses.Add("VehicleLoan", vehicle.MonthlyLoanPayment());
       
        Console.WriteLine($"Monthly repayment for vehicle is {monthlyExpenses["VehicleLoan"]:C2}");

    }
    private void RentPayment()

    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your monthly rent amount: ");
        monthlyExpenses.Add("Rent", GetExpenses());

    }
    private decimal GetRemainingMoney() 
    {

        decimal expenses = 0;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < monthlyExpenses.Count; i++)
        {

            expenses += monthlyExpenses.ElementAt(i).Value;

        }

        return monthlyExpenses["Income"] - expenses;

    }
    private int GetOption() 
    {
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        bool option = Validate.ValidateInt(answer);

        while (option==false)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            option = Validate.ValidateInt(answer);
            if (option==true && (Convert.ToInt32(answer)!=1 || Convert.ToInt32(answer) != 2))

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid answer");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();

            }

        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(answer);

    }
    protected decimal GetExpenses()
    {

        dynamic expense = "";
        
        while (Validate.ValidateDecimal(expense) == false)
        {

            expense = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Validate.ValidateDecimal(expense) == true && Validate.ValidatePositve(Convert.ToDouble(expense)) == true)
            {
                return Convert.ToDecimal(expense);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid answer");
        }

        return 0;

    }
    public IDictionary<string, decimal> monthlyExpenses { get; set; } // Properties... stores all of the income and expenses from the user

}
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 

namespace ExpensesCalculator
{
public class Program : Expenses
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var program = new Program();
        program.GetMonthlyExpenses(ExpensesAlert); // Calls the override method
        
    }

    public override decimal MonthlyLoanPayment() // Method is not needed
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static void ExpensesAlert(IDictionary<string, decimal> expenses) // Method used in the delegate
    {
        // This method calculates if the expenses is greater than 75% of the income
        decimal total = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < expenses.Count; i++)
        {

            total += expenses.ElementAt(i).Value;

        }

        decimal expenesPercent = ( total / expenses["Income"]) * 100 ;

        if (expenesPercent>=75)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\aYou current expenses ({total:C2}) exceed 75% of your total income ({expenses["Income"]:C2})!");
        }

    }
}
}
```

**Vehicle.cs**

```
using System;
using ValidateTypeLibrary;

namespace ExpensesCalculator
{
class Vehicle : Expenses
{
    public override decimal MonthlyLoanPayment()
    {
        dynamic price, deposit, interestRate,insurance;
        string name=null;
        int NumOfMonths = 60; // Repayment is assumed to be repaid over five years (60 months)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following details: ");

        Console.Write("Model and make: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        while (Validate.ValidateString(name)==false)

        {

            Console.Write("Enter a valid answer: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        Console.Write("Purcase price: ");
        price = GetExpenses();

        Console.Write("Total deposit: ");
        deposit = GetExpenses();

        Console.Write("Interest rate: ");
        interestRate = GetExpenses();

        Console.Write("Estimated insurance premium: ");
        insurance = GetExpenses();

        // A = P(1+in) this formula will be used to calculate the home loan repayment, formula was modified to return the monthly repayment

        decimal A = price - deposit; // P 
        A = A * (1 + ((interestRate * 0.01m) * (NumOfMonths / 12))); // n = number of years 
        return (A / NumOfMonths) + insurance; //returns the monthly payment for the loan

    }
}
}
```

**HomeLoan.cs**

```
using System;
using ValidateTypeLibrary;

namespace ExpensesCalculator
{
public class HomeLoan : Expenses
{
    public override decimal MonthlyLoanPayment()
    {
        // Gets the info for the home loan

        dynamic price, deposit, interestRate, NumOfMonths;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following details: ");

        Console.Write("Purcase price of the property: ");
        price = GetExpenses();

        Console.Write("Total deposit: ");
        deposit = GetExpenses();

        Console.Write("Interest rate: ");
        interestRate = GetExpenses();

        Console.WriteLine("Number of months to repay (Between 240 and 360 months): ");
        NumOfMonths = GetExpenses();

        while (NumOfMonths < 240 || NumOfMonths > 360)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Between 240 and 360 months");
            NumOfMonths = GetExpenses();

        }

        // A = P(1+in) this formula will be used to calculate the home loan repayment, formula was modified to return the monthly repayment

        decimal A = price - deposit; // P 
        A = A * (1 + ((interestRate * 0.01m) * (NumOfMonths / 12))); // n = number of years 
        return A / NumOfMonths; //returns the monthly payment for the loan
     
    }
    
}
}
```

**Validator.cs**

```
using System;

namespace ValidateTypeLibrary
{
public static class Validate
{
    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is int type
    public static bool ValidateInt(dynamic value)
    {

       // int temp;

        if (int.TryParse(value, out int temp))

        {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is decimal type
    public static bool ValidateDecimal(dynamic value) 
    {
         
        decimal temp;

        if (decimal.TryParse(value, out temp))

        {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is double type
    public static bool ValidateDouble(dynamic value)
    {
       
        double temp;

        if (double.TryParse(value, out temp))

        {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is char type
    public static bool  ValidateChar(dynamic value)
    {

        char temp;

        if (char.TryParse(value, out temp))

        {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is float type
    public static bool ValidateFloat(dynamic value)
    {
        float temp;

        if (float.TryParse(value, out temp))

        {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is string type and cannot be empty
    public static bool ValidateString(string value)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    // Validates the user input as the input required from the user must be positive
    public static bool ValidateNegative(double value) 
    {
        if (value > 0)

        {

            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }

    // Validates the user input as the input required from the user must be negative
    public static bool ValidatePositve(double value)
    {
        if (value < 0)

        {

            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }
}
}
```

All the classes and libraries have been included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Dictionary` or any `Key` based collection, ensure that you use a better technique to store / retrieve the value by the key. As using `string` as key is not an issue if you have limited usage for it, however, with bigger projects it will be hard to maintain. As alternative, you could use `enum` or you can store the keys as `const` and reuse them.

Example :

```
// USE ONLY ONE 
// Enum OR Constant 

//
// With enum
//
public enum ExpensesName 
{
    Income,
    Tax,
    Groceries
    //.. etc
}

//
// OR With constant
//
public struct ExpensesName
{
    public const string Income = "Income";
    //.. etc
}
```

Now, using one of them would give you this usage :

```
// add income 
monthlyExpenses.Add(ExpensesName.Income, GetExpenses()); 

// get income
var income = monthlyExpenses[ExpensesName.Income];
```

This is just a way of managing the keys. However, if you have predefined keys you could declare it with default values in the dictionary and just set their values when needed something like this :

```
public abstract class Expenses
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, decimal> _monthlyExpenses = new Dictionary<string, decimal>
    {
        { "Income", 0 },
        { "Tax", 0 },
        { "Groceries", 0 }
        // ..etc
    }
    
    public void SetIncome(decimal value)
    {
        // throw if negative value
        if(value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        
        _monthlyExpenses["Income"] = value;
    }
    
    public decimal GetIncome() 
    {
        return _monthlyExpenses["Income"];
    }
}
```

This would let you handle each value separately, and store them all in one predefined dictionary. It's acceptable approach for some senarios, however the better approach would be to have a class model that would hold these values something like this :

```
public class MonthlyExpenses
{
    public decimal Income { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Groceries { get; set; }
    public decimal Utilities { get; set; }
    public decimal Travel { get; set; }
    public decimal Phone { get; set; }
    public decimal Other { get; set; }
}
```

With this, you can initiate a new instance of `MonthlyExpenses` and assign the values as needed, then you can pass the instance into any other class or method to reuse its values. This approach is widely used, as it's more maintainable and readable, and can also be extended with more related operations (e.g. adding `Validate()` method to check wither the properties are having the correct values or not) and better yet, it's intellisense supported.

The second note is that mixing between user-interface logic, and the core logic, is not a good practice, it needs to be separated. So the code can be  adapted with future changes without breaking the core logic such as converting from Console to ASP.NET or Console to Windows Form ..etc.

To have a better abstraction, the current abstraction needs to implement the minimum requirements, so revising the current one would be something like this :

```
public abstract class SimpleInterestBase
{
    public decimal Principal { get; }

    public decimal Deposit { get; }

    public decimal InterestRate { get; }

    public decimal Insurance { get; }

    public int TotalMonths { get; }
    
    public SimpleInterestBase(decimal principal, decimal deposit, decimal interestRate, decimal insurance, int numberOfMonths)
    {
        Principal = principal;
        Deposit = deposit;
        InterestRate = interestRate;
        Insurance = insurance;
        TotalMonths = numberOfMonths;
    }
    
    
    public virtual decimal GetMonthlyPayment()
    {           
        decimal interestRatePerYear = 1 + ((InterestRate * 0.01m) * (NumberOfMonths / 12));
        decimal totalAccruedAmount  = Principal - Deposit;
        totalAccruedAmount *= interestRatePerYear;
        totalAccruedAmount /= NumberOfMonths;
        return totalAccruedAmount  + Insurance;
    }

}
```

Now, we can implement it on the `HomeLoan` and `VehicleLoan` :

```
public class HomeLoanSimpleInterest : SimpleInterestBase 
{ 
    public HomeLoanSimpleInterest(decimal principal, decimal deposit, decimal interestRate, decimal insurance, int numberOfMonths)
    : base(principal, deposit, interestRate, insurance, numberOfMonths) { }
}

public class VehicleLoanSimpleInterest : SimpleInterestBase 
{
    public VehicleLoanSimpleInterest(decimal principal, decimal deposit, decimal interestRate, decimal insurance)
    : base(principal, deposit, interestRate, insurance, 60) { }
    
}
```

I've changed the abstract class name to the actual purpose name, this would give a better understanding on what the class does, and why it's there.

Now, you can implement a class that would process the user input and validate it, then whenever you get the required values, you initiate the `SimpleInterestBase` instance (wither for home or vehicle) and return the results to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Expenses` class isn't only expenses - it includes an income as well, so I think a more sensible name could be `Budget`.

`Program` should not inherit from `Expenses`.

Separate your budget calculations from your budget entry logic.

Your `delegate` is, in one sense, a good idea: it allows for business logic code with no printing to call into a user interface class that does have printing. But this is better-represented with a parameter-less `Action event`. This event should only be invoked when the affordability threshold is exceeded.

Your dictionary representation of expenses is not a great idea. You should hold onto a reference of your income. You should also have a domain object that represents a single budget line item.

You can, in a budget class, automatically check for affordability warnings after the addition of every expense via a utility method.

Your roman numerals are incorrect, and should count iv, v for phone and other expenses.

Instead of `* 0.33`, just `/ 3`.

`GetRemainingMoney` is simple enough that it can be represented as a `RemainingMoney` property, particularly if you use a Linq sum.

Don't write `option == false`; just write `!option`. However, this validation pattern is awkward and hasn't abstracted the right things in your utility functions. Notice that you actually parse the string twice - once to check whether it's parseable, and another time to actually parse it. This should only happen once.

Consider using the new braceless namespace syntax sugar.

`NumOfMonths < 240 || NumOfMonths > 360` can be simplified using an `is/or` expression.

Don't use `\t` - it's basically never going to look right. Use fixed-width string padding in interpolation expressions instead.

This:

```
monthlyExpenses.OrderBy(key => key.Value);
```

has been mis-implemented, because first of all it sorts in the wrong direction, and also the result is thrown away since this is not in place.

A first pass that covers most of the above is:

### Suggested

**Budget.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Budget
{
    public readonly decimal Threshold;
    public readonly LineItem Income;
    private readonly List<LineItem> _expenses = new();
    
    public event Action? OnUnaffordable;

    public Budget(LineItem income, decimal threshold = 0.75m)
    {
        Income = income;
        Threshold = threshold;
    }

    public void AddExpense(LineItem expense)
    {
        _expenses.Add(expense);
        WarnAffordable();
    }

    public decimal ExpenseSum =>
        _expenses.Select(e => e.Amount).Sum();

    public decimal RemainingMoney =>
        Income.Amount - ExpenseSum;
    
    public bool Affordable =>
        ExpenseSum < Threshold * Income.Amount;

    public void WarnAffordable()
    {
        if (!Affordable)
            OnUnaffordable?.Invoke();
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<LineItem> ExpensesDescending =>
        _expenses.OrderByDescending(e => e.Amount);
}
```

**BudgetReader.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

using System;

public class BudgetReader
{
    public readonly Budget Budget;
    
    public BudgetReader()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following monthly quantities:");

        LineItem income = LineItem.FromConsole(
            heading: "a)", name: "gross income (before deductions)"
        );
        
        Budget = new Budget(income);
        Budget.OnUnaffordable += WarnAffordable;
    }

    private void WarnAffordable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Your current expenses of {Budget.ExpenseSum:C2} exceed " +
            $"{Budget.Threshold:P} of your income {Budget.Income}!");
    }
    
    public void FillFromConsole()
    {
        Budget.AddExpense(LineItem.FromConsole(heading: "b)", name: "estimated tax deducted"));
        Budget.AddExpense(LineItem.FromConsole(heading: "c)", name: "expense: groceries"));
        Budget.AddExpense(LineItem.FromConsole(heading: "d)", name: "expense: utilities"));
        Budget.AddExpense(LineItem.FromConsole(heading: "e)", name: "expense: travel costs (including petrol)"));
        Budget.AddExpense(LineItem.FromConsole(heading: "f)", name: "expense: cell phone and telephone"));
        Budget.AddExpense(LineItem.FromConsole(heading: "g)", name: "expense: other"));

        int option = Validator.GetOption("Would you like to", "rent", "buy property");
        LineItem propertyItem = option switch
        {
            1 => RentPayment(),
            2 => HomeLoanPayment(),
            _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
        };
        Budget.AddExpense(propertyItem);

        option = Validator.GetOption("Would you like to buy a vehicle?", "yes", "no");
        if (option == 1)
            Budget.AddExpense(VehiclePayment());
    }

    public void DisplayExpenses()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your remaining month for the month after all deductions is: {Budget.RemainingMoney:C2}");

        string banner = new('-', 51);
        Console.WriteLine("Your monthly expenses in descending order:");
        Console.WriteLine(banner);
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Expense",40} {"Amount",10}");
        Console.WriteLine(banner);

        foreach(LineItem expense in Budget.ExpensesDescending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{expense.Name,40} {expense,10}");
        }
    }

    private HomeLoan HomeLoanPayment()
    {
        HomeLoan homeLoan = HomeLoan.FromConsole("Home loan");
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Your monthly repayment for the house is {homeLoan}");

        // The user loan should be more than a third of their gross income for a likely approval of a home loan
        Console.Write("Approval of home loan is ");
        if (homeLoan.Approvable(Budget.Income))
            Console.WriteLine("likely");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("unlikely");

        return homeLoan;
    }

    private Vehicle VehiclePayment()
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = Vehicle.FromConsole();
        Console.WriteLine($"Monthly repayment for vehicle is {vehicle}");
        return vehicle;
    }

    private static LineItem RentPayment() =>
        LineItem.FromConsole("Rent amount");
}
```

**HomeLoan.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

using System;

public record HomeLoan(
    string Name,
    decimal Amount
) : LineItem(Name, Amount)
{
    public HomeLoan(
        string name,
        decimal price,
        decimal deposit,
        decimal yearInterestRate,
        decimal nMonths) :
        this(name, CalculateAmount(price, deposit, yearInterestRate, nMonths))
    {}

    private static decimal CalculateAmount(
        decimal price,
        decimal deposit,
        decimal yearInterestRate,
        decimal nMonths)
    {
        decimal
            nYears = nMonths / 12,
            totalAmount = (price - deposit) * (1 + yearInterestRate * nYears),
            monthAmount = totalAmount / nMonths;
        return monthAmount;
    }
    
    public static HomeLoan FromConsole(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following mortgage details:");

        decimal price = Validator.GetDecimal("Purchase price of the property"),
            deposit = Validator.GetDecimal("Total deposit"),
            yearInterestRate = Validator.GetDecimal("Yearly interest rate %")/100;

        decimal nMonths;
        do
        {
            nMonths = Validator.GetDecimal("Number of months to repay (Between 240 and 360 months)");
        } while (nMonths is < 240 or > 360);

        // A = P(1+in) this formula will be used to calculate the home loan repayment;
        // formula was modified to return the monthly repayment

        return new HomeLoan(name, price, deposit, yearInterestRate, nMonths);
    }

    public bool Approvable(LineItem income) =>
        Amount < income.Amount / 3;
    
    public override string ToString() => $"{Amount:C2}";
}
```

**LineItem.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

public record LineItem(
    string Name,
    decimal Amount
)
{
    // Validates the user input as input required from the user is decimal type
    public static LineItem FromConsole(string name, string heading = "")
    {
        string promptName;
        if (heading == "")
            promptName = name;
        else promptName = $"{heading} {name}";

        return new LineItem(name, Validator.GetDecimal(promptName));
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Amount:C2}";
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BudgetReader reader = new();
        reader.FillFromConsole();
        reader.DisplayExpenses();
    }
}
```

**Validator.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

public static class Validator
{
    public static int GetOption(string question, params string[] options)
    {
        string prompt = 
            question 
            + ' '
            + string.Join(
                ", ",
                options.Select(
                    (name, i) => $"{name} ({i+1})"
                )    
            )
            + ": ";
        
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            string answer = Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new EndOfStreamException();
            if (int.TryParse(answer, out int value)
                && value > 0
                && value <= options.Length)
                return value;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option");
        }
    }

    public static decimal GetDecimal(string name)
    {      
        string prompt = $"{name}: ";
        
        while (true) {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            string answer = Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new EndOfStreamException();

            if (decimal.TryParse(answer, out decimal amount) && amount >= 0)
                return amount;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid amount");
        }
    }

    public static string GetString(string name)
    {
        string prompt = $"{name}: ";
        while (true) {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            string answer = Console.ReadLine() ?? throw new EndOfStreamException();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
                return answer;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid answer");
        }
    }
}
```

**Vehicle.cs**

```
namespace ExpensesCalculator;

public record Vehicle(
    string Name,
    decimal Amount
) : LineItem(Name, Amount)
{
    public Vehicle(
        string name,
        decimal price,
        decimal deposit,
        decimal yearInterestRate,
        decimal monthInsurance,
        decimal nYears
    ) : this(name, CalculateAmount(price, deposit, yearInterestRate, monthInsurance, nYears))
    {}

    private static decimal CalculateAmount(
        decimal price,
        decimal deposit,
        decimal yearInterestRate,
        decimal monthInsurance,
        decimal nYears)
    {
        // A = P(1+in) this formula will be used to calculate the home loan repayment;
        // formula was modified to return the monthly repayment

        decimal 
            nMonths = 12 * nYears,
            remain = price - deposit,
            totalAmount = remain * (1 + yearInterestRate * nYears),
            monthAmount = totalAmount / nMonths + monthInsurance;
        return monthAmount;
    }
    
    public static Vehicle FromConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following vehicle details:");
        
        // Repayment is assumed to be over five years (60 months)
        const int nYears = 5;

        string name = Validator.GetString("Model and make");

        decimal
            price = Validator.GetDecimal("Purchase price"),
            deposit = Validator.GetDecimal("Deposit"),
            yearInterestRate = Validator.GetDecimal($"Yearly interest rate ({nYears} years) %")/100,
            monthInsurance = Validator.GetDecimal("Monthly insurance premium");

        return new Vehicle(name, price, deposit, yearInterestRate, monthInsurance, nYears);
    }
    
    public override string ToString() => $"{Amount:C2}";
}
```

### Output

```
Please enter the following monthly quantities:
a) gross income (before deductions): 100000
b) estimated tax deducted: 30000
c) expense: groceries: 200
d) expense: utilities: 200
e) expense: travel costs (including petrol): 200
f) expense: cell phone and telephone: 200
g) expense: other: 200
Would you like to rent (1), buy property (2): 2
Please enter the following mortgage details:
Purchase price of the property: 500000
Total deposit: 20000
Yearly interest rate %: 1.5
Number of months to repay (Between 240 and 360 months): 350
Your monthly repayment for the house is $1,971.43
Approval of home loan is likely
Would you like to buy a vehicle? yes (1), no (2): 1
Please enter the following vehicle details:
Model and make: honda car
Purchase price: 20000
Deposit: 100
Yearly interest rate (5 years) %: 1
Monthly insurance premium: 100
Monthly repayment for vehicle is $448.25
Your remaining month for the month after all deductions is: $66,580.32
Your monthly expenses in descending order:
---------------------------------------------------
                                 Expense     Amount
---------------------------------------------------
                  estimated tax deducted $30,000.00
                               Home loan  $1,971.43
                               honda car    $448.25
                      expense: groceries    $200.00
                      expense: utilities    $200.00
expense: travel costs (including petrol)    $200.00
       expense: cell phone and telephone    $200.00
                          expense: other    $200.00
```